# Show all relationships between two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have a single table that has data like the following:

Column 1 -- Column 2

A -- Z

A -- Y

B -- Y

I am looking for a way in MySQL to roll up this data so that I get the following table that will show group associations:

Column 1 -- Column 2

A,B -- Z,Y

I can use the group_concat function to get one column at a time grouped together, but I need both columns to be grouped to show the relationships.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Try `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`. Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html

Answer (score 5):

This will work.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;
```